# Is OR/M available in .NET core web API project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, ado.net, entity-framework-core

In ASP.NET Framework projects one could right click the project and add a ADO.NET Entity Data Model using an existing database. This would create classes and properties from database's tables and columns.

But this option is missing from ASP.NET Core API web application project. What can I use to create these classes from existing SQL Server database, or is that not possible?

[image: VS add ORM to project]

Comment: If you want to stick with Entity Framework, check out EF Core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/ There are some command line tools you can use to generate classes from the tables. I recently started using Dapper and am impressed by its simplicity (although you'll have to roll the classes yourself): https://dapper-tutorial.net/

Comment: And, if you want to use EF/EF Core in a database-first-ish way, check out the Reverse POCO Generator https://www.reversepoco.co.uk/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This worked

In Package Manager Console:

1. `Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`
2. `scaffold-dbcontext "your_connection_string" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -outputdir Models -Table table1,table2`

If you get an error that "The term 'scaffold-dbcontext' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet...", see this question: [The term 'scaffold-dbcontext' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39454545/1541224)

Answer (score 2):

Try to execute the following command under your project folder:

```sh
$ dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=....." Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServe
r -o Models
```

And fill the string `Server=.....` with your database connection string. Make sure that you can connect to this database successfully.

[image: command]

And EF will try to build models from the database.

[image: generated]

Reference: https://anduin.aiursoft.com/post/2020/2/13/creating-a-model-for-an-existing-database-in-entity-framework-core

Comment: I tried `Scaffold-DbContext` in Package Manager Console but got `Scaffold-DbContext : The term 'Scaffold-DbContext' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.` Let me try this method